# Perfomance SQL Where Clause with column

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2014, where-clause

I have a couple of tables that look whether a "normal suscription" (A) is valid from a certain date. and a "trial Subscription" (B) that has a cancellation date.

```
TABLE A
ValidFrom   id
2022-09-24  1
2022-01-25  2

TABLE B
id  cancellationDate
1   2023-07-16
2   2023-07-16
1   2023-06-05
2   2019-07-04
1   2016-10-01
1   2023-12-16
1   2017-10-28
```

by trying to figure out whether there is a subscription after the trial period  I created the following query.

```
 SELECT        
      Sales.B.CancellationDate
     ,Y.ValidFrom  
 FROM            Sales.A AS Y  
 INNER JOIN 
     Sales.B ON Y.id = Sales.B.id 
 WHERE
     Sales.B.CancellationDate >  Y.ValidFrom
     ORDER BY 1
```

which will return the following:

```
CancellationDate    ValidFrom
2023-06-05  2022-09-24
2023-07-16  2022-09-24
2023-07-16  2022-01-25
2023-12-16  2022-09-24
```

**I was wondering if there is *a better way* to improve the performance of the following:  ( Consider that indexes are there )**

```
Sales.B.CancellationDate >  Y.ValidFrom
```

I have the feeling that the DB Engine is doing a N x M Comparisons in order to get the result and do the BOOLEAN true.

EDIT:

Indexes/Table:

```
CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20181107-194645] ON [Sales].[B](    [id] ASC)
CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20181107-194645] ON [Sales].[A](    [id] ASC)

CREATE TABLE [Sales].[A](
        [ValidFrom] [date] NULL,
        [id] [tinyint] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[B](
       [id] [tinyint] NULL,
       [cancellationDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You can view the _actual execution plan_ to see how the database engine has decided to process the query. (In SSMS: Query -> Include Actual Execution Plan)

Comment: "Consider that indexes are there" but you didn't show any indexes on the Dates columns - Adding an index on id and date column in both tables should improve performance of this query.

Comment: Hi Zohar, and HABO. even If I run the execution plan, and add new columns to the indexes and having all the indexes properly set up  ( perfect state), is there any way to create, write, the WHERE clause that gives a better performance?

`Sales.B.CancellationDate >  Y.ValidFrom`